# COMO MUESTRO EL ULTIMO REGISTRO DEL CUSTOMERID 11000?

Tags: sql-server

El unico registro que quiero que salga es el 1 - 11000 /57418 /13851.34

```
USE AdventureWorks2019

select SO.CustomerID, max(SO.SalesOrderID) as 'Ultima Compra', 
round(sum(SO.TotalDue),2) as 'Total'
from Sales.SalesOrderHeader as SO
join Sales.SalesOrderDetail  as SOD 
on (SO.SalesOrderID = SOD.SalesOrderID)
where SO.CustomerID in ('11000')
group by SO.SalesOrderID, SO.CustomerID
order by SO.SalesOrderID asc, SO.CustomerID desc
```

Comment: ¿Qué es "ultimo registro del customerid" para ti? ¿Qué es 11000? te recomiendo que leas [ask], cambies la imagen por codigo y nos expliques que sucede para que podamos ayudarte

Comment: Consejo: por favor, evita las mayúsculas sostenidas. Puedes [edit] tu pregunta, seguir las recomendaciones en los comentarios y ampliar la info para recibir mejores respuestas :) Gracias!

Comment: Pon tu código como texto, no como imágen.